# notion of generating in definition of standard probability space

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space

and there's this quote:

> A measurable function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$  is called
>   generating if $\mathcal{F}$  is the completion of the
>   σ-algebra of inverse images $f^{-1}(B)$,  where $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ runs over all Borel sets.
>
> Caution.  The following condition is not sufficient for $f$  to be
>   generating: for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$  there exists a Borel set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$  such that $P ( A \Delta f^{-1}(B) ) = 0$.

I don't get the second paragraph. The condition in the second paragraph looks like an equivalent condition to me.